# clicked hover bug (chrome)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When applying `:hover-attributes`, and clicking (hold left mouse button) on a cell while moving the cursor over the other rows, only the first clicked row gets highlighted on hover:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghk8j16k/)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    width: 40px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
tr:hover {
    background-color: #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In other major browsers (IE, FF) it will highlight all other rows as expected.

Is this a chrome bug? Or feature? How to get all 3 major browsers behave the same?

---

*If you get a cross-cursor when trying to reproduce, try again several times.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ghk8j16k/1/

Comment: Thanks! The problem is, all this stuff is based on a veeery large table and causing performance-issues. That's why i cannot use javascript to add classes on hover, which will result in more poor performance leack. If i cannot fix this in CSS, I have to wait for the fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is a bug I believe](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=122746). Is there a use case in which you would need :hover to be triggered in this situation?

Comment: No but avoid hover. So when using pointer-events:none while clicked the table (i.e. scrolling with jQuery dragscrollable Plugin) the hover-effect causes serious performance-issues on IE when hovering, while scrolling.

Short: This very little bug causes serious trouble here.